# Visual Studio Code Terminal

Tags: visual-studio, terminal, windows-10

procurei bastante na NET e no Stack e não consegui encontrar a resposta para esta minha pergunta. Então vamos lá.

Tenho o Windows 10 instalado na minha máquina, e estou tentando me adaptar ao Visual Studio Code ( EM JAVA )? Quando vou rodar a aplicação aparece MUITOS códigos sem ser os da aplicação. No Eclipse, Netbeans, quando rodamos a aplicação só aparece o código escrito por nós.
Será possível alguma configuração que também colocasse o VSCODE só aparecendo os códigos que escrevemos na saída ou no Terminal ??? Colocarei uma imagem para esclarecer minha dúvida. As setas vermelhas são as que eu gostaria de tirar... e aparecer só o código da seta verde que foi a saída que pedi para a aplicação imprimir na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo `launch.json` é só setar o parâmetro `"console":None`

O arquivo normalmente é criado quando você cria um workspace no VS Code

Comment: Consegui mudando essa propriedade ai. Muito Obrigado.

https://imgur.com/Wh8beSV